# Manga/anime/game: protagonist suffered accident that made him see monsters except for one girl

Tags: story-identification, anime, video-games, manga

I’m trying to identify a manga/anime/game/comic, these are the clues:

- Protagonist suffered some kind of head injury during an accident.
- He saw humans including his own friends look like monsters.
- He saw his environment (house, wall, chair, floor) looked like a bloody (red) organic disgusting mess.
- Suddenly a little girl that appeared normal and only this girl looked normal.
- He fell in love with the girl, and he become abhorrent of his own friends due to their appearance to him.
- The girl in reality is the monster, who looked not even humanoid but some kind of moving flesh with tentacles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Song of Saya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saya_no_Uta)* (2003), a Japanese computer game.

> Fuminori Sakisaka is a young medical student whose life completely changes when he is involved in a car accident along with his parents, killing them and heavily wounding him, leaving him with a brain disorder, which symptoms manifest as an exaggerated form of agnosia, that causes him to see the world as covered in gore and people as hideous monsters. As he contemplates suicide in the hospital, he soon meets someone named Saya, who he sees as a beautiful young girl.... Due to their circumstances, Fuminori and Saya become close and move in together, eventually becoming lovers and incredibly dependent on one another.

However the girl is the monster, and since the protagonist sees the world as monstrous, including ordinary humans, he gets depressed by it until the appearance of Saya the only 'human' looking creature.

He falls in love with Saya, and is even willing to kill other human beings for her. She is, in fact, a monster with tentacles, an escaped experiment by some scientist, who eats human beings.

[image: In-game image of Saya looking human]

Comment: This game got voted as one of the most messed up games ever made. Just sayin'